# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.applySchema

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query on a file stored in hdfs using sqlcontext provided in Apache Spark using the below code but i am getting a NoSuchMethodError

```
package SQL

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object SparSQLCSV {   def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]","home")
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val people = sc.textFile("/home/devan/Documents/dataset/peoplesTest.csv")
    val delimiter = ","
    val schemaString = "a,b".split(delimiter)//csv header
    //Automated Schema creation
    val schema =   StructType(schemaString.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
    val peopleLines = people.flatMap(x=> x.split("\n"))
    val rowRDD = peopleLines.map(p=>{
      Row.fromSeq(p.split(delimiter))
    })
    val peopleSchemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
    peopleSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("people")
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT b FROM people").foreach(println)

  } }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.applySchema(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
>           at scalding.Main_Obj$.main(Main_Obj.scala:34)
>           at scalding.Main_Obj.main(Main_Obj.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I have tried the same using command line provided in spark, and it works but when i create a scala project and try to run it i get the above error. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Try changing `  val rowRDD = peopleLines.map(p=>{
      Row.fromSeq(p.split(delimiter))
    })`     to     `  val rowRDD = peopleLines.map(p=>{
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(p.split(delimiter)))
    })`

Answer (score 7):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually means that you have incompatibles between libraries.  In this particular case it looks like you might be using a version of spark-csv that requires Spark 1.3 with an older version of Spark.