# Spark MLlib example, NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-mllib

I'm following the documentation example [Example: Estimator, Transformer, and Param](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-estimator-transformer-and-param)

And I got error msg

> 15/09/23 11:46:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaUniverse$JavaMirror;
>     at SimpleApp$.main(hw.scala:75)

And line 75 is the code "sqlContext.createDataFrame()":

```
import java.util.Random

import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

import scala.io.Source

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._


import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{ALS, Rating, MatrixFactorizationModel}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object SimpleApp {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[4]");
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
       val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
       val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
         (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.1, 0.1)),
         (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.0, -1.0)),
         (0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0, 1.3, 1.0)),
         (1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.2, -0.5))
       )).toDF("label", "features")
    }
}
```

And my sbt is like below:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "hello",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= {
    Seq(
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "1.4.1",
        "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.4.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "1.4.1" % "provided"
    )
}
```

I tried to search around and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543400/nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-spark-sql-sqlcontext-applyschema) which is very similar to my issue, and I tried to change my sbt setting for spark versions (spark-mllib_2.11 to 2.10, and spark-1.4.1 to 1.5.0), but it came even more dependency conflicts.

My intuition is it's some version problem but cannot figure it out myself, could anyone please help? thanks a lot.

Comment: You should add `spark-sql` to the dependencies.

Comment: @zero323 thanks I'll add it and try it out

Comment: @zero323 it did not work, still same error. I'm thinking maybe it's because here "val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
     val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame()", where I new the wrong class with no such method?

Comment: @keypoint: 1. Try scala 2.10.2   2. Then replace `% "spark-mllib_2.11"` by `%% "spark-mllib"` 3. Add spark sql as zero323 suggested.

Comment: @zero323: It is an error at runtime and not a compilation error. So a missing import should be noticed on compile.

Comment: @zero323 I ran "sbt compile" and "sbt package" and both command ok, and I did have "import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext"

Comment: @MartinSenne thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: @MartinSenne it works! thank you so much :P

Comment: @keypoint: Glad to hear that!!! By the way, you can upvote comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now for me, and just for the record, referencing @MartinSenne answer.

what I did is as below:

1. clear all compile files under folder "project"
2. scala version **2.10.4** (previously using 2.11.4)
3. change spark-sql to be: "**org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1" % "provided"**
4. change MLlib to be: **"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.4.1" % "provided"**

@note:

1. I've already started a Spark cluster and I use "**sh spark-submit /path_to_folder/hello/target/scala-2.10/hello_2.10-1.0.jar**" to submit jar to Spark master. If use sbt to run by command "**sbt run**" will fail.
2. when changing from scala-2.11 to scala-2.10, remember that the jar file **path and name** will also change from "**scala-2.11/hello_2.11-1.0.jar**" to "**scala-2.10/hello_2.10-1.0.jar**". when I re-packaged everything, I forgot to change the submit job command for the jar name, so I package into "hello_2.10-1.0.jar" but submitting "hello_2.10-1.0.jar" which caused me extra problem...
3. I tried both "val sqlContext = **new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)**" and "val sqlContext = **new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)**", both are working with method *createDataFrame()*