# HiveContext.sql() gives runtime No Such Method Error

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Hi I am trying to run a simple java program using Apache Hive and Apache Spark. The program compiles without any error, but on runtime I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
at SparkHiveExample.main(SparkHiveExample.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Following is my code:

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
 import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
 import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
 public class SparkHiveExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkHive Example");
 SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
 HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);

 System.out.println("Hello World");
 DataFrame df = hiveContext.sql("show tables");
 df.show();
 }
}
```

My pom.xml file looks as follows:

```
<project>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I tried using SQLContext.sql() method and I still get a similar method not found runtime error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712576/6526073) stackoverflow answer suggests that the problem is caused due to dependency problem, but I am unable to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your spark core and spark hive dependencies are set to the scope of `provided` as shown below. These dependencies are provided by the cluster and not by your application.

And ensure the version of your spark installation is 1.3 or above. prior to 1.3 the `sql` method returned a RDD (SchemaRDD) instead of DataFrame. It is most likely the version of spark that is installed is older than 1.3.

```
 <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

And it is recommended you use `SparkSession` object to run queries instead of HiveContext. The below code snippet explains the usage of SparkSession.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("spark session example")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("show tables")
```

Comment: Even after adding the scope tag, I get the same error. My Spark version is 2.1.1

Comment: @AnishKanchan if you using spark 2.1.1 you should use spark session object to run your hive queries not `HiveContext`. can you please try the above snippet i have added in the answer?

Comment: This worked! Thanks! So which version of Spark supports HiveContext? Also, the hive tables are not visible to me when using SparkSession. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: SparkSession was introduced from Spark 2.0. HiveContext is to be used for prior versions. did you call `enableHiveSupport` while creating your sparksession?. if did Hive tables should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are applying `query` of showing table and assigning to a `Dataframe`.

You can assign to a `DataFrame` when you use `select query` or similar queries but not `show query`

Comment: Even if I put a SELECT query there, I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType,StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Your APPName").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(spark)

hive_context.sql("select current_date()").show()
```

Comment: Please explain your answer further, why and how you got here.. just pasting code doesn't constitute as a proper answer.